# Accessing Image URL on Orchard using razor

Tags: asp.net-core, orchardcms

I am using Orchard CMS. I am trying to access an image URL on a razor page as per the first image attached.
The output I get through google inspection is also attached as second image. I am simply trying to get rid the square braces so that I access the actual image file

I tried these:

@post.Content.Images.Images.Paths.[0]
@post.Content.Images.Images.Paths.first()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIXwv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi7ZR.png)

Comment: Write code as code. Do not post screenshots of your code

Answer (score 1):

```
@Orchard.AssetUrl(post.Content.Images.Images.Paths[0])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked like magic, though it need the string conversion.@Orchard.AssetUrl((string)post.Content.Images.Images.Paths[0])